# Textview doesn't get updated for display device language from firebase

Tags: android

I know it's very simple bug but ı can't find any solution.I'm trying to get different text from firebase for display language.If display language is Turkish get "Kayantr",and get "Kayanen" for any other language.I changed device language many times but it's always show "Kayantr".

```
    private FirebaseAuth user;
    TextView scrollingText;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.baydogru.iddaatahminleri.R.layout.activity_ana_ekran);

        scrollingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scrollingtext);
        scrollingText.setSelected(true);

/*other codes*/

try {
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    if (!Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().equals("tr")) {
                        scrollingText.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Kayantr").getValue().toString());

                    } else {

                        scrollingText.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Kayanen").getValue().toString());

                    }
/*other codes*/
```

Also i tried make scrollingtext as string variable and use = operator instead .setText , but result not changed.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
if (Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().equals("Türkçe")) {
        scrollingText.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Kayantr").getValue().toString());

} else {

        scrollingText.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Kayanen").getValue().toString());

}
```

Comment: you can use as an alternaive
`code`Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().equals("tur") or `code`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("tr")